# MS-Access form: weird behavior

Tags: vba, ms-access, subform

I have a bound form with a subform bound to a different recordSource, although these recordSources can be linked through a field.

I have an unbound text-box control in my main form and a button control, with custom vba code attached to its OnClick event.

What I want to achieve is something like this: (pseudo-code for easier reading)

```
private sub button_Click()
    'Find the record with the content of the text-box control as its value in FieldA
    find(mainForm.RecordSource, fieldA, text-box.value) 
    if not found then
    'Create a record in the subform.recordSource with PK value = text-box.value
        createDefaultRecord(subform.Form.RecordSource,text-box.value)
    end if
    'load the values in the record in the main record source onto the record in the subform recordSource
    Me!subform.Form.value = mainForm.recordThatMatched.value
Exit Sub
```

And I actually get it to work, but with a minor inconvenience: if I **introduce a code *that has not yet generated its record*** in subform.RecordSource, it creates it and then **fails** to load it **BUT** if you try to **load a different code or close the form** and then **reload the first code** again, **IT WORKS!**

Any idea as to why this is happening or how to code a work-around to this situation? It really is bugging me. I have tried to run `acSaveRecord` and `acSave` before loading the record but the ending remains the same: I cannot load on the subform a record recently created without navigating first through the main form's records (which is kinda stupid and counter-intuitive)

I may be wrong in my diagnosis and that would be OK to point out, too. I don't have that much experience with Access and VBA.

Comment: My guess: you need a `Me!subform.Form.Requery` after adding the record. It would be easier if you'd show the actual code.

Comment: That was exactly it. Since I have learned VBA through a quick tutorial I lack some of this basic knowledge of its "built-in functions". Thanks a lot! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was to add this:

```
Me!subform.Form.Requery
```

after adding the record.

A form (or subform) doesn't show newly added records in its recordsource unless it is requeried (manually with Shift+F9 or via code).